# Attempting to understand Python (for translation to C)

Tags: python, c, translate

I've been trying to understand the following Python program to translate it in C, but I meet some difficulties, here it is :

```
ROB = '\x00\xA1\x0F\xC0'

def my_function(f):
  for c in range(0,len(f),4):
    if f[c:c+4] == ROB:
      f = f[:c] + f[c+4:] # What does it even means ???
      print '%p' % c
      return f
  print 'ERR'
  sys.exit(-1)
```

I mean, I understood the most of the function but one of these lines is literally hard to translate (I talk about `f[:c] + f[c+4:]`) ...

Does someone know what this line is doing or how it should looks like in C ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Not directly answering to your question, have you tried Python-C transpiler or compiler? For example, I use Nuitka and it gives a good performance boost in most cases.

Comment: You cannot rewrite directly into C, because C has no "counted strings" (and the 4-bye fragment contains a NUL). So you'll need to keep track of the actual  size-used of the char[] object.

Comment: `f = f[:c] + f[c+4:]` just erases substring "ROB". To do this in C, simple copy both parts into another string with enough size. Like `oldstr[c]=0; snprintf(newstr, size, "%s%s", oldstr, oldstr+4);`

Comment: If I understood right, it should be : `char *var[c] = 0; snprintf(f, sizeof(f), "%s%s", var, var+4);` ? (I wonder if `memcpy()` wouldn't be useful too ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are "slices", and the `+` simply concatenates them. This is the simplest case of slicing, `[start:end]` creates a subsequence of a sequence, starting from position `start` inclusive, ending at position `end`, exclusive. If one of them is missing (but the `:` is there), it is considered to be the beginning/end of the complete sequence. Indices are zero based.
Examples with string:

- `'Hello World'[1:5]`: `'ello'`
- `'Hello World'[:5]`: `'Hello'`
- `'Hello World'[1:]`: `'ello World'`
- `'Hello World'[:1]+'Hello World'[5:]`: `'H World'`

Your loop steps through your data in 4-byte steps, comparing the 4-byte chunk at the current position with the sequence you have in `ROB`, and it returns a new sequence without it when it is found (so the `f=...` part does not actually modify the existing sequence).
In C you could do that with `memcmp`, then `malloc` and a pair of `memcpy` calls, as you correctly noticed that this data is binary (contains null-characters), so string functions would likely break it.
Hopefully I did not messed up the indices, and then it could look like this:

```
void* my_function(const void* f, int len){
  for(int i=0;i<len;i+=4)
    if(memcmp(f+i,ROB,4)==0){
      void* ret=malloc(len-4);
      memcpy(ret,f,i);
      memcpy(ret+i,f+i+4,len-i-4);
      return ret;
    }
  return NULL; // or have it die somehow
}
```

Comment: @Lisbakc `memcpy(f, ROB, 4);` in particular would copy the first 4 bytes of `ROB` at the beginning of `f`. That may or may not be what you need, I can't tell.

Comment: A side comment: if `len` (length of the original sequence) may be something not divisible by 4, `for(int i=0;i<len-3;i+=4)` is the safe solution. This way the function does not try to check the last chunk in `f`, if it is shorter than 4 bytes (and thus it can not equal to `ROB`).